# How to make the bot not said the language code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, text-to-speech

I'm trying to code discord tts bot but I run into a problem. When I used `$speak en Hi guys` the bot said `"en hi guys"`.

I tried making the bot not say the language code but I can't so if you have any solution please share it with me.

Here is my code:

```
const { getAudioUrl } = require('google-tts-api')

let language = args[0]
 
if(!language) return message.reply("Please enter the language")     
if(!text) return message.reply("Please enter the text")
const text = args.join(" ")
 if(text.length > 200) return message.reply('You cant input a text with over 200 characters')
 const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
 if(!voiceChannel) return message.reply(" Please enter a voice channel") 
                                    
 const audioURL = await getAudioUrl(text, {
 lang: language, 
 slow: false, 
 host: 'https://translate.google.com', 
 timeout: '150000'
 })

 try {
   voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
     const dispatcher = connection.play(audioURL)
     dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
       voiceChannel.leave()
     })
   })
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove the first item (`"en"`) from your `args` array and `join` the rest:

```js
const text = args.slice(1).join(" ")

if(!text) return message.reply("Please enter the text")
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help, but you know how to set the 2minutes timeout for the bot? so it will not leave after speaking

Comment: It sounds like a different question. This one answered your original question, so I'd appreciate it if you could upvote it and click the checkmark to accept it, so others with similar problems would know that it worked.

Comment: As for the timeout, you could use `setTimeout(() => voiceChannel.leave(), 2 * 60 * 1000)` for example. If you don't want it to leave the channel, simply remove `voiceChannel.leave()`.